# How to create plugin settings page for each admin user?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, options

I have to develop a plugin where it is required that each admin user should have different settings for the plugin. Forexample, email settings should be different for each user, lets say user A filled his settings and saved them, and now user B logs in , he shouldn't be seeing User A settings instead his settings form should be a new one just for him. I tried to look on google for it but apparently there are not many answers in this domain.

Comment: Why don’t you use user_meta for storing these settings?

Comment: That's a good option. But i wanted to use native plugin settings options method.  But if there is no other way then i will go for meta. Thanks for response.

Comment: Handy: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: user_meta functions are the native functions to handle what you want to do.